# (Java Minecraft 1.13) How to test for if a beacon is activated?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to use `execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:nether_star", Count:1b}}] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:beacon run...` but only if the beacon is activated. Is there a way to do this without checking every block of the underlying structure to make sure it is complete? Basically, what is the id/nbt of a Beacon which can be used to test for if it is activated?

Comment: Do you mean "active" as in "shining light" or as in "providing selected status effect"?

Comment: @FabianRöling As in shining light.

Comment: I just answered for both cases now, that's more helpful for future readers and it's almost the same anyway. I did this all just from memory and the wiki, so please tell me if one of the commands isn't working right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For NBT questions the Minecraft wiki page ["Chunk format"](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Chunk_format&oldid=1364153)) always helps. It can tell you that the "`Level`" tag of a beacon stores the number of layers of the pyramid that are available to it (with the usual small delay), "`Primary`" stores the first and "`Secondary`" the second status effect.

So you can do something based on that check like this:

```
/execute if block ~ ~ ~ beacon{Level:1} run <command>
```

But that only works for a single value, not all four. You could use `execute store` with `data get` to put it into a scoreboard, then you could check for a range, but since you are only interested in "not 0", you can use this:

```
/execute if block ~ ~ ~ beacon unless block ~ ~ ~ beacon{Level:0} run <command>
```

This would in theory also select beacons without the `Level` tag, but that doesn't happen unless it's explicitly removed with commands (or the world gets corrupted or whatever).

---

If you want to check for the effect instead, you can do something like this:

```
/execute if block ~ ~ ~ beacon unless block ~ ~ ~ beacon{Primary:{Id:0b}}
```

The value 0 in a beacon's effect ID means "no effect".

Comment: Update in 1.14.0: The "Level" tag is broken currently, so you would have to check every block and every possible variant.